# Python Tkinter unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'IntVar'

Tags: python, tkinter

I have looked all over google to find the solution to my code but I can't find any.

Here's my code, it's a simple clicker like game(Just trying to learn the basics of Tkinter). What I want to do is collect oil, then sell it, but I need my current oil counter to go to 0 so I don't make infinite money.:

```
from tkinter import *
import sys

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x300")
root.title("oil clicker")

counter = IntVar()
cash = IntVar()
def onClick(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() + 2)


def negOnClick(event=None):
    cash.set(cash.get() * 45)
    counter.set(counter.get() - counter)

addLabel = Label(root, textvariable=counter).pack()
addButton = Button(root, text="Increase", command=onClick, fg="dark green", bg = "white").pack()
negetiveLabel = Label(root, textvariable= cash).pack()
negetiveButton = Button(root, text="Sell oil for cash", command=negOnClick, fg="dark green", bg = "white").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When I run the program then try and sell the oil it gives me this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Blank/Documents/python clicker game/test2.py", line 16, in negOnClick
    counter.set(counter.get() - counter)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'IntVar'
```

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Right about `counter.set(...)` you're setting `counter = totalamount`. Do you mean to do that?

Comment: I just updated my code but now I'm getting a different error.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain (in your question itself, not these comments) what the program is supposed to do. In its current state, the `negOnClick` function doesn't make much sense, so we have to guess what you really want it to do.

Comment: You should update the code in your question with the new error you're getting so we can see what's happening.